# Cross-project dependencies with Maven in NetBeans

Tags: java, maven, javafx, architecture

[image: GUI layer, with which I want to call methods]

[image: Domain layer which holds the methods to be called]

I want to be able to access classes and methods from within another project. I GUI is located in the presentation layer project, and inside that project I have set dependencies to the project I want to be able to call methods from, the domain layer, but it doesn't work. How can I access classes and objects between objects with Maven?

Comment: Sorry for the horrible formatting of this post!

Comment: There's an [edit] link below the post that allows you to modify the question, if you're not satisfied with the formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a new dependency to the dependencies in your GUI pom should do.
Just add

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
<artifactId>domainlayer</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

To make sure your domainlayer gets built before the GUI, add it as a module to the GUI pom.

```
<modules>
    <module>domainlayer</module>
</modules>
```

Once you built the module domainlayer with `mvn clean install`, it is provided as a dependency in your local repository on your system.